# Video File Not Playing file Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

hello I have a function to download file save to Docs Dir and then play it . The File is download and saved .. the path are the same but the message is that can not player. 
Here is

My Download Function code.

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
{
    NSLog(@"Temporary File :%@\n", location);
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURL *docsDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"welbi.mp4"]];
    if ([fileManager moveItemAtURL:location toURL:docsDirURL error: &err])
    {
        //NSLog(@"File is saved to =%@",docsDir);
        NSLog(@"File path is   ----> %@",[docsDirURL absoluteString]);
        [self playVideo:[docsDirURL absoluteString]];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"failed to move: %@",[err userInfo]);
    }
}
```

and this is my Video Player Function.

```
- (void) playVideo:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
   filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *appDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURL *fileDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[appDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
    NSLog(@" URL Video ===> %@", [fileDirURL absoluteString]);

    //MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController;

    playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[fileDirURL absoluteString]]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
        object:[playerViewController moviePlayer]];

    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];

    //play movie

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];
    player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [player play];
}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification 
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        removeObserver:self
        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
        object:player];
    [player stop];

    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I checked and the file paths are exactly the same...  but it gives me this error message

```
2014-08-01 12:13:30.972 training[16793:90b] File path is   ----> file:///Users/Russelius/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/D92411C3-EBEA-4CEA-B1EB-DAC8AB986599/Documents/welbi.mp4
2014-08-01 12:13:30.973 training[16793:90b]  URL Video ===> file:///Users/Russelius/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/D92411C3-EBEA-4CEA-B1EB-DAC8AB986599/Documents/file:/Users/Russelius/Library/Application%2520Support/iPhone%2520Simulator/7.1/Applications/D92411C3-EBEA-4CEA-B1EB-DAC8AB986599/Documents/welbi.mp4
2014-08-01 12:13:31.539 training[16793:90b] _itemFailedToPlayToEnd: 
{
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Looking at the log you will see your path start with `file//` your player expect the path to your file **not** the absolute path.

**Solution**

Solution is to replace `absoluteString` with `path`

```
NSLog(@"absolute path is   ----> %@",[docsDirURL absoluteString]);
NSLog(@"File path is   ----> %@",[docsDirURL path]);
[self playVideo:[docsDirURL path]];
```